# SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 52092

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and I am trying to connect my app to the MySQL database(localhost) using Larval API. When I am trying to connect to the database I am encountering this error.
E/flutter ( 4305): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 52092
E/flutter ( 4305):
I am using VSCODE.
I have checked a lot of solutions but nothing works.

Here is my code
Method to call API

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future<void> getProducts() async {
    var url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/product";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    print(response.statusCode);
  }
```

Comment: Did you use the IP address for the local host?